# Where is the error in the react?

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I built the file using commands:

> browserify -t reactify js/[app.js](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/reactjs-learn/blob/master/js/app.js) -o js/[build.js](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/reactjs-learn/blob/master/js/build.js)

When [starting in the browser](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/reactjs-learn/blob/master/3.html), an error occurs:

```
build.js:196 Uncaught TypeError: React.render is not a function
    at Object.2.react (build.js:196)
    at s (build.js:1)
    at e (build.js:1)
    at build.js:1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React vs ReactDOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114350/react-vs-reactdom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` is no longer part of `'react'`. If you want to render to a DOM element, import `render` from `'react-dom'`.

Comment: I added var ReactDOM = require ('react-dom'); In the file app.js but the error remained the same. Maybe need to add something else?
https://github.com/StekolschikovV/reactjs-learn/blob/master/js/app.js

Comment: You're still saying `React.render`. It's `ReactDOM.render`.