# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Where did I get wrong?. I've been following a tutorial but it always gives me this error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. and What would cause the prop to become undefined. 
here's my code:

```
var todoItems = [];
todoItems.push({index: 1, value: "learn react", done: false});
todoItems.push({index: 2, value: "Go shopping", done: true});
todoItems.push({index: 3, value: "buy flowers", done: true});

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var items = this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
                return (
            <TodoListItem key={index} item={item} index={index} removeItem={this.props.removeItem} markTodoDone={this.props.markTodoDone} />
    );
    });
        return (
            <ul className="list-group"> {items} </ul>
    );
    }
}

class TodoListItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClickClose = this.onClickClose.bind(this);
        this.onClickDone = this.onClickDone.bind(this);
    }
    onClickClose() {
        var index = parseInt(this.props.index);
        this.props.removeItem(index);
    }
    onClickDone() {
        var index = parseInt(this.props.index);
        this.props.markTodoDone(index);
    }
    render () {
        var todoClass = this.props.item.done ?
            "done" : "undone";
        return(
            <li className="list-group-item ">
            <div className={todoClass}>
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.onClickDone}></span>
        {this.props.item.value}
    <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.onClickClose}>&times;</button>
        </div>
        </li>
    );
    }
}

class TodoForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.itemName.focus();
    }
    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newItemValue = this.refs.itemName.value;

        if(newItemValue) {
            this.props.addItem({newItemValue});
            this.refs.form.reset();
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <form ref="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="form-inline">
            <input type="text" ref="itemName" className="form-control" placeholder="add a new todo..."/>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </form>
    );
    }
}

class TodoHeader extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <h1>Todo list</h1>;
    }
}

export default class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
        this.markTodoDone = this.markTodoDone.bind(this);
        this.state = {todoItems: todoItems};
    }
    addItem(todoItem) {
        todoItems.unshift({
            index: todoItems.length+1,
            value: todoItem.newItemValue,
            done: false
        });
        this.setState({todoItems: todoItems});
    }
    removeItem (itemIndex) {
        todoItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        this.setState({todoItems: todoItems});
    }
    markTodoDone(itemIndex) {
        var todo = todoItems[itemIndex];
        todoItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        todo.done = !todo.done;
        todo.done ? todoItems.push(todo) : todoItems.unshift(todo);
        this.setState({todoItems: todoItems});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main">
            <TodoHeader />
            <TodoList items={this.props.initItems} removeItem={this.removeItem} markTodoDone={this.markTodoDone}/>
    <TodoForm addItem={this.addItem} />
    </div>
    );
    }
}
```

and it always points to the `var items = this.props.items.map((item, index) => ...`. I don't think [this](https://gist.github.com/marekdano/615f2310e9154b2d75ba) tutorial has an error. I'm still new in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with tutorial, but you missed one part,
Check the last line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp initItems={todoItems}/>, ....);
```

There `todoItems` is passed into component in props so `this.props.todoItems` will have the initial data, but in your case you are exporting the component and rendering it somewhere else and not passing the data to `TodoApp` component that's why `this.props.todoItems` is `undefined`.

Since you define the data in the same file, So use the local data directly.

Write it like this:

```
<TodoList items={todoItems} ....
```

**Other solution:**

Instead of defining the data into this file define it where you are importing TodoApp and rendering it, and pass the data from that place it will work.

Like this:

```
import TodoApp from '/path_to_todoapp/';

var todoItems = [];
todoItems.push({index: 1, value: "learn react", done: false});
todoItems.push({index: 2, value: "Go shopping", done: true});
todoItems.push({index: 3, value: "buy flowers", done: true});

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp initItems={todoItems}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**Update:**

Use `ReactDOM.render`, check this answer for more details: [React vs ReactDOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114350/react-vs-reactdom)

Comment: it gives me this error: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.render is not a function