# What's difference between RBuilder and RDomBuilder?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop, kotlin-frontend

In the kotlin react demo projects i see both

`fun RBuilder.someComponent(){...}`

and

`fun RDOMBuilder<*>.someComponent(){...}`

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RDOMBuilder` is part of the [kotlin-react-dom](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-react-dom) wrapper, whereas `RBuilder` is part of the [kotlin-react](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-react) wrapper. Depending on what library you want to use, the one or the other `Builder` may be used.

Comment: what if i use both? could you please explain the difference for dummies? are they interchangeable?

Comment: @ deviant you'll need the react-dom if ReactDOM is used: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html; the following gives more information on the differences of both libs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34114665/8073652