# What does React-dom do

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and someone who usually use create-react-app for my projects.

As I was exploring, I saw [npm react-dom package](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom).

which also happens to be inside our create-react-app

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

But for some reason, the documentation for the same looks vague and hard for **me** to comprehend.

so, can someone please explain what does react-dom does?

Comment: Use search BEFORE asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114350/react-vs-reactdom

Answer (score 1):

React as a library is not limited to web only. It can be used to create "native" iOS/Android apps. It can even be used to create VirtualReality experiences!

So `react` package contains the library core, while packages like `react-dom` are used to integrate React into specific platforms:

- `react-dom`: Web integration. DOM stands for [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)
- `react-native`: Integration into native iOS and Android apps
- `react-360`: Integration into VR platform

And there are many more!